# SSKeychain/SSKeychainQuery.h file not found

Tags: ios, security, keychain

I added the SSKeychain class files manually as mentioned in the read me. Also added the Header Search path to the folder. Still I am getting this error. Following are the steps i followed

To manually add to your project:

Add Security.framework to your target
Add SSKeychain.h, SSKeychain.m, SSKeychainQuery.h, and SSKeychainQuery.m to your project.

Comment: Are they listed in `Build Phases - Link Binary With Libraries`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "Header Search Path" under "Build Settings".
you can add "$(PROJECT_DIR) recursive" , you will see option at the end of the row.
Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Did you mean to finish this statement "you can add $(PROJECT_DIR) re"?